# Angularjs modify dynamically ng element in HTML

Tags: angularjs

I have an exemple as this one:

```
<div id="test" ng-repeat="foo">
```

I would like to change in my script the ng-repeat to something else (for example foo to foo2) when i do something (clicking on a button for example).
Is it possible ?

Thank you a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to change in my script the ng-repeat to something else (for example foo to foo2) when i do something (clicking on a button for example). Is it possible ?

#### Short Answer

**No**

AngularJS parses `ng-repeat` directive value and expects pattern `item in collection`

But you can replace list through which you iterate.

```
<div id="test" ng-repeat="item in foo()">
```

where `foo()` might be some method that returns array of objects

> But is it possible to change the function foo() with foo2() dynamically ?

you can write method `foo()` as:

```
$scope.foo = function(){

   if($scope.clicked){
    return array1;
   }
   alse{
    return array2;
   } 
 }
```

#### Details

From [Angular_6.6](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js)

```
var expression = $attr.ngRepeat;
      var ngRepeatEndComment = $compile.$$createComment('end ngRepeat', expression);

      var match = expression.match(/^\s*([\s\S]+?)\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+as\s+([\s\S]+?))?(?:\s+track\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?\s*$/);

      if (!match) {
        throw ngRepeatMinErr('iexp', 'Expected expression in form of \'_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]\' but got \'{0}\'.',
            expression);
      }
```

The pattern is:

```
/^\s*([\s\S]+?)\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+as\s+([\s\S]+?))?(?:\s+track\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?\s*$/
                  ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is it possible to change the function foo() with foo2() dynamically ? I have: " <div id="test" ng-repeat="item in foo()"> ", i click on a button and then i have " <div id="test" ng-repeat="item in foo2()"> " ?

Comment: @C.Norris on click you can change that `foo()` will return different list

Comment: @C.Norris you can also use `ng-if` to switch between 2 divs

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat into `foo` and change it without problem when clicking on button. It's working using a third variable between your two arrays that you want to repeat.

**[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z8A5qcJCLqLh5PoxIGTI?p=preview)**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in choice">{{x}}</div>
  <button ng-click="switch()">Switch</button>
</div>
```

---

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
  $scope.itemsAlternative = [6,7,8,9];

  $scope.choice = $scope.items;
    $scope.choice = ($scope.choice == $scope.items) ? $scope.itemsAlternative : $scope.items;
  }
})
```